# How would I go about putting text (variable) on the top of a file without rewriting the whole file in php?

Tags: php

How would I go about putting text (variable) on the top of a file without rewriting the whole file in PHP? I have 3 files: `index.php`, `form.php`, and `process.php`.

`form.php` has a form on it that I can enter data into, and it will pass the info though POST to `process.php`.

`process.php` will get the info from `form.php` and run the info in variables. I will take the variables and use them to create a file (`index.php`) and then write the info to the file which would be `index.php`.

I'd like to get my script to do this: Take the form info and store the info in variables on `config.php` then once that's done it will include it on `index.php` on the top without rewriting all of `index.php`.

process.php:

```
`<html>
   <head>
      <title>configure</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php 
         include('config.php');
         $user = $_POST["name"]; 
         $page_name = $_POST["page_name"];
         $page_title = $_POST["page_title"];
         $message = $_POST["message"];
         print("<h1>congratulations!</h1><br><h2>Your have created your page</h1><a href=$page_name.php>Here</a>");
         $out = fopen("$page_name.php", "a"); 
         if (!$out) { 
            print("Could not append to file"); 
            exit; 
         } 
         fputs ($out,implode,("\n")); 
         fwrite($out,"<html>\n");
         fwrite($out,"<head>\n");
         fwrite($out,"<title>$page_title</title>\n");
         fwrite($out,"</head>\n");
         fwrite($out,"<body>\n");
         fwrite($out,"<h1>$message</h1>\n");
         fwrite($out,"</body>\n");
         fwrite($out,"</html>\n");
         fclose($out);
      ?>
   </body>
</html>`
```

form.php:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Configure</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="process.php" method="POST">
         Your Name:<br />
         <input type="text" name="name"><br />
         Page Name:<br />
         <input type="text" name="page_title"><br />
         Page Title:<br />
         <input type="text" name="page_name"><br />
         Your Message:<br />
         <textarea name="message"></textarea><br />
         <input type="submit" value="Send Info">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: dude its no problem helping you. But please post some code. Thanks

Comment: dear you have three file, post the code for all. and update your question, dont give me the code in comment, cause i might not have a solution, if you post in the question, other will see that as well, and you will likely to have a solution. Thanks

Comment: Sory I posted the code sorry im still learning how to use this site lol

Comment: its ok dude, i am going some where, i will have look after 20 minutes. but one more advice, dont give a link, most of the people dont want to click the link here. So final advice post the code here. and explain in your question what you are trying to achieve. and what you are getting. Thanks

Comment: dear, correct me if i am wrong. when ever someone click on the submit, you want them to send the info to the `config,php` and than to `index,php` thats easy by using session, but have feeling, correct me if i am wrong, you want all info, means lets say 10 people submit there info, you want them all into index.php. Thanks

Comment: Pretty much im making a site like word press to make changing text and logos easy for myself I want to to keep one file and use that as a template and have the form make a file like config.php and store the info into the file then add the file with an include to the template file to pull the info and apply it to the page make and sense?

Comment: yes id does make sense. And i dont wanna leave you by saying its to broad. If you want to changing the text easy for your self, first you need all text, than you should have one box. which let you choose the text style from, from that, and apply that text that particular page. google it you will find ready made solution. else typing the whole let of text style going to take you ages. other people do the same. Second you want same for your user do that. for that you need database. you just have to get their info from the database. and you dont need to right any code. php will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot that't a lot better than someone saying it too "Broad"!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to pass the parameters from the form submitted to process.php and then back to index.php. You don't really have to do it that way. Just post the data to the same file you're on (index.php). Which means, edit the form to this `<form action="" method="POST">` and do your validation in the index.php file. You then have access to the `$_POST` content.

Comment: Ok I will do that but what im trying to do is I have a website template and I want to put variables in the template where it will pull the info from the config page that is made when the form is submitted making it easy to change text ect.

Comment: It seems like you need a database driven website in that case, if you want to permanently store the form inputs. Read up on [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for more info on how to do that.

Comment: Im trying to do the same thing that word-press dose. where it creates a sight from the template and make a file so I can easily set up websites using my template without a lot of work editing files ect.

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow. There are plenty of tutorials out there that you can use.